# How to call a function from a function within a workflow

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a Powershell workflow with a number of functions inside it.

My code, and the error...

```
workflow New-AutomationVM
{
    function Pre-DeploymentChecks
    { Write-Output $true }

    function Deploy 
    { $checkResult = Pre-DeploymentChecks }

    Deploy
}
New-AutomationVM
```

> The term 'Pre-DeploymentChecks' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

My intention was to create a deploy function that encapsulated all of the other functions. But it seems not possible to call a function from within a function within a workflow. i.e. I can call Pre-DeploymentChecks from the workflow, but not the function.

Obviously I could just put that logic outside of the functions, but this approach seemed a little tidier.

Am I doing something stupid! or is this just not possible within Powershell workflows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested workflows instead:

```
workflow New-AutomationVM
{
    workflow Pre-DeploymentChecks
    { Write-Output $true }

    workflow Deploy 
    { $checkResult = Pre-DeploymentChecks }

    Deploy
}
New-AutomationVM
```

This also allows you to use workflow constructs inside each nested workflow, such as `sequence` or `parallel`:

```
workflow New-AutomationVM
{
    workflow Pre-DeploymentChecks
    {
        function Check-IP
        { return $true }

        function Check-Name
        { return $true }

        function Check-Role
        { return $false } 

        $CheckResults = parallel {
            sequence {
                Check-IP
                Check-Name
            }
            Check-Role
        }

        ($CheckResults |Where-Object {-not $_}) -le 1 
    }

    workflow Deploy 
    {
        Pre-DeploymentChecks
    }

    Deploy
}
New-AutomationVM
```